# How to import MaterialX library into blender?

Tags: materials, shaders, gpu, library

Does anyone have any idea how to get the [MaterialX](https://matlib.gpuopen.com/main/materials/all) library into blender as the picture below showcases?

[image: Material library in Blender]

I'd love to use this since AMD is not able to get Cycles X to work with Polaris cards for a good few years now but there aren't much if any resources out there explaining people how to use the USD hydra plug in with MaterialX (or how to use the plugin in more detail - no tutorials, no wikis, nada). If you can point me in the direction of a good knowledge base i'd be much grateful.

Comment: Hello ! you might have already seen this https://blenderartists.org/t/materialx-blender-integration/700331

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the USD Hydra addon: [GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/BlenderUSDHydraAddon](https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/BlenderUSDHydraAddon)

---

### Edit 2024-04-02:

Apparently this feature was migrated to this addon instead: [bnagirniak/RPRHydraRenderBlenderAddon](https://github.com/bnagirniak/RPRHydraRenderBlenderAddon)

But when it comes to older Blender versions [prior to this change](https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/BlenderUSDHydraAddon/pull/274), I guess you might need to use a version of BlenderUSDHydraAddon contemporary of the concerned Blender version.

---

Download the [latest release](https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/BlenderUSDHydraAddon/releases/latest), and install it like any other addon.

Then in Properties Editor > Render Properties Tab: Switch the render engine to USD Hydra:

[image: render engine]

Finally, go in the Properties Editor > Materials Tab > Material Library Panel:

[image: mat lib]

It takes time to fetch all the materials (I guess it needs to download them), so be patient to get the full list.